# Rails Parameterize using Transliterate Doesn't work with Arabic/Unicode Strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, activesupport

I have a string containing Arabic charachters **"محمود"**

When I try to parameterize this string, it returns empty string ""

```
x = "محمود"
x.parameterize    => ""
```

I have checked parameterize code and found it calls I18n.transliterate which returns question marks "?????"

I tried to customize transliteration referring to previous question [How do you customize transliterations in a Rails 3 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976070/how-do-you-customize-transliterations-in-a-rails-3-app)

But still returning blank string.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `parameterize` method is supposed to render the string URL safe, and there's a strict limit on what kind of characters can appear in the URL. Generally anything not strictly `a-z` or `0-9` or `-` is stripped.

You could always try and fix it so that multi-byte UTF-8 characters are admitted by default. The current implementation is really quite lacking. Instead of allowing only a small set of specific characters, a more robust version would strip out the troublesome ones.

Comment: You are right, I had to implement it my self x.gsub(/\s+/, "-").gsub( /[^a-zA-Z0-9أ-ي-]*/ , "")

Comment: Why do you need this `gsub( /[^a-zA-Z0-9أ-ي-]*/ , "")`